# WAMP-response content length limit?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to get big data(200M) from php(Phalcon) via ajax(jQuery).
But when I'm debugging, I find I can get the big data in php(use `echo $reply`to transfer data) while javascript gets empty (response data is empty).
I have tried to use 100M data and it works well. So I am wondering is there response content length limit? If so, how can I configure it?
Phalcon code:

```
$reply = json_encode(array(
  "msg" => "success",
  "content" => $content, // size over 200M
), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$reply_len = strlen($reply);
header("Content-Length: $reply_len");
echo $reply;
$this->view->disable();
```

JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://localhost/swift-service/file/download',
  type: 'POST',
  data: post_data
}).done(function (data) {
  //data == ""
}).fail(function (data) {

})
```

Comment: Check your error log. Check your `php.ini` for `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time`.

Comment: `memory_limit`&`max_execution_time` are big enough.`[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7080:tid 412] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7080:tid 412] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[core:notice] [pid 7080:tid 412] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7080:tid 412] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8308
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8308:tid 352] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.`

Answer (score 0):

you can configure max limits in your php.ini file

you have not describe the problem in detail so just giving all in one solution (not recommended)

open php.ini file and change in the following..

max_execution_time
max_input_time
post_max_size

personally I think main problem for you is your max_execution_time, which will be set to 30sec default, which you can change to 120 for testing.

Comment: I've tried to modify the php.ini file. But it doesn't work. I still get empty response. I've put some code above.